# How to wrap a character with a span tag after rendering

Tags: javascript, html, string, reactjs

I have a randomly generated string passed as props to a child component. Which displays it in a paragraph tag.
Example strings can be:

cat, dog, bird

bird, fish, hamster, goose

cat, fish, dog

etc..

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    string: ''
  };


  componentDidMount() {
    let newString = this.props.passedString.replace(',', '<span>,</span>');
    this.setState({string: newString});
  }

  render() {
    return (  
      <div><p>{this.state.string}</p></div>
    )
  };
}
```

I want to add  tag around each comma inside the child component's paragraph.
I tried to add `componentDidMount` method which replaces each comma with comma wrapped in a span tag in the string, but for obvious reason this just adds the span tags as part of the string and I do not know how to display them as actual tags in the html or how to modify the already rendered paragraph.

Comment: so what do you do to render it currently?

Comment: I modified my post to make it easier

Comment: How about using .`split` by comma, and loop the span inside render function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) methods to produce the JSX that achieves what you require:

```
/* Split the input randomString by `,` in to an array of string part */
const stringParts = randomString.split(',');

/* Use map to transform each string part to a React.Fragment. Prepend a
   comma enclosed by <span> for any string part that's not the first in
   the array */
const wrappedParts = stringParts.map((stringPart, index) => {

    return <React.Fragment>
    { index === 0 ? null : <span>,</span>}{stringPart}
    </React.Fragment> 
})
```

Here's a functional component showing this in action:

```css
span {
background:lightgrey;
margin:0.1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="module"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">

  const MyComponent = (props) => { 
    const { randomString } = props;
    
    return randomString.split(',').map((stringPart, index) => {

        return <React.Fragment>{ index === 0 ? null : <span>,</span>}{stringPart}</React.Fragment> 
    })
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <MyComponent randomString={ 'bird, fish, hamster, goose' } />
      <hr/>
      <MyComponent randomString={ 'cat, dog, bird' } />
      <hr/>
      <MyComponent randomString={ 'cat, fish, dog' } />
    </div>, 
  document.getElementById("module"));
</script>
```

Comment: The OP was very clear in the question: "I want to add tag around each _comma_". Your answer doesn't do that.

Comment: @Andy ah sorry about that - updated answer. Very true, was staring me right in the face. I should probably go to sleep ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative involves the use of [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), along with [String#split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and other `Array` methods.

In your example, you could delete the `componentDidMount()` method, and replace the `render()` one with the following.

```
render() {
  const splitString = this.props.passedString.split(",");
  <div><p>
    { splitString.slice(1).reduce((total, stringPart) => {
        total.concat([(<span>,</span>), stringPart])
      }, [splitString[0]])
    }
  </p></div>
}
```

Notice that the first part is included in the initial answer, and excluded from the process that add leading spans; this allows to avoid the index comparison.